# How do I grep starting at a specific point in a log file?

Tags: grep

A have daily syslog files which contain syslog messages in the format: `MMM DD HH:MM:SS additional_data_here`

We make a change, then want to see if the syslog messages continue.

For example, say a change was made at 09:55. I want to ignore everything prior to the first line that contains `Oct 29 09:55:00`. Then I want to grep for my error message after that first line match.

For this example, I have to create several different statements, like this:

`grep -e "Oct 29 09:5[5-9]" syslog20211029 | grep "[my message]"`

`grep -e "Oct 29 1[0-1]:" syslog20211029 | grep "[my message]"`

But I do this often enough that I'd like to find a better, more consistent way. Something like:

`start-at-first-match "Oct 29 09:55:00" syslog20211029 | grep "[my message]"`

But I don't know what the start-at-first-match option is. Any suggestions?

Comment: The date format used is conceivably bad. I recommend changing to `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`.

Comment: Would changing the format somehow help answer the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to restrict yourself to using `grep`, you can't really but with the option `-A` *num* it can still meet your need (giving a big number for *num*) :

```
grep -A 10000000 "Oct 29 09:55:00" syslog20211029
```

This will print the matching line and the next 10 million.

If you want everything that follows the line for sure (without having to give an "unreachable" number of lines), you have to use another command (like `sed` or `awk`). Using `sed`: `sed -n '/Oct 29 09:55:00/,$ p'` (with `-n` won't print the lines by default, and from the line you want, between `/pattern/`, to the end of file `$` you ask `sed` to `p`rint the lines).